# Both a generic constraint and inheritance

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have this scenario:

```
class A<T>
```

I want a constrain of type Person like

```
class A<T> where T: Person
```

and I want A to inherit from B too.

example:

```
class A<T> : B : where T: Person
```

or

```
class A<T> where T: Person,  B
```

how can I do it?

Comment: I hope my edits were correct, but your original title makes me wonder. It doesn't seem like you want 'or', but that you want *both* the inheritance and the constraint.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
class A<T> : B where T : Person
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't inherit from *more than one* class in C#. So you can have

`A<T>` inherites from `B` and `T` is `Person` (`Person` is either *class* or *interface*):

```
class A<T>: B where T: Person {
  ...
}
```

`A<T>` doesn't necessary inherites from `B`; but `T` inherites from `B` and implements `Person` (`Person` can be  *interface* only):

```
class A<T> where T: Person, B {
  ...
}
```

It seems that you want case 1:

```
// A<T> inherites from B; 
// T is restricted as being Person (Person is a class or interface)
class A<T>: B where T: Person {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I am not referring to multiple inherit is just a constrain over the generic type, and.... inherit from other class

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking how to express this structure in C#? If so below one example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        B a1 = new A<Person>();
        B a2 = new A<ChildPerson>();
    }
}
class Person
{
}

class ChildPerson : Person
{
}

class A<T> : B where T: Person
{
}

class B
{
}
```

Comment: Good example, including the `ChildPerson` class for illustration. Maybe just for clarity add a note that you only added that class for illustration; it's not required for the requested functionality?

Answer (score 0):

There is no multiple inheritance in C#, therefore you cannot enforce that a type inherits from  multiple classes.

Sounds like your structure is incorrect.

To ensure both are implement, either one of them has to be an interface, or one of them has to implement the other.

If you mean T can implement B or Person then, then there should be some abstract base class/interface that B and Person share which you restrict to that

Comment: I am not referring to multiple inherit is just a constrain over the generic type, and.... inherit from other class